# How to do invalidation of all cache files at a time in nginx?

Tags: nginx

How I can invalidate all accumulated cache by opening special url on cache server?

When using Nginx Plus I can use proxy_cache_purge directive for it. Can I do it without proxy_cache_purge? For invalidate specific cache file I tried to use https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_cache_purge module, but I can not reset all cache.

P.S. cache have very much files (millions), so just delete cache folder this is the bad idea

Comment: I don't understand why it's a bad idea to delete everything in the cache directory.  Is the issue one of synchronization?  Perhaps you should try using a symlink to your cache directory, and then switch the symlink to another directory when you want to clear it out.

Comment: Because delete million big files, for example each 100MB, it is long time process. Maybe symlink will work, thanks. I will study this case

Comment: The size of the file doesn't matter.  When you delete the file, only the reference to the data on disk is removed.

Comment: `proxy_cache_purge` doesn't work with regex, you need to specify a particular key to be deleted. It basically purges cache directory entries so it won't be faster.